# Уважаемые эксперты . Как правильно рассчитать параметры vps server-а с учетом расчетной нагрузки трафик в день 250k пользователей?

Tags: php, mysql, vps

Я понимаю что вопрос не совсем корректный и рассчитать придельное количество пользователей достаточно сложно так как от этого зависит много факторов но все же . Возможно есть формула для приблизительного расчета максимального количества пользователей который может выдержать сервер . Вши мысли господа

Comment: 250k разделить на 86400 - это считай 3 запроса в секунду. Это вообще не нагрузка.

Comment: @u_mulder смотря что там делают пользователи, может там фото/видео закачка/обработка, или активно работает curl.

Comment: @u_mulder пользователь делает не 1 заход на сайт а ползает по нему худо бедно. + на каждый гет запрос потянется еще штук 10-20 запросов к стилям/js/картинкам. + пользователи вряд ли будут распределены равномерно по всем суткам.

Comment: "каждый гет запрос потянется еще штук 10-20 запросов к стилям/js/картинкам" - только первый запрос, браузер все закеширует. думаю вам надо как то замерить среднее время выполнения запросов, ибо как правильно заметил Jean-Claude , может быть написана логика для которой и 100 пользователей хватит что бы положить сервер. а вообще лучше задать этот вопрос хостингу, они и подскажут опираясь на свои тарифы, и быстро его поправят если выяснится что мощностей не хватает.